# Downgrade kernel for ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I am currently on ubuntu 22.04 LTS release which comes with kernel version `5.15.0-27-generic`. I want to downgrade to kernel version `5.13` because of touchpad problem in my lenovo thinkbook.

Is it possible to downgrade the baked in kernel in 22.04 LTS release? If yes, how do I achieve it?

Comment: You read a tutorial which explains how to install a custom kernel in Linux.

Comment: Yes, but will the system work because 22.04 comes with kernel version 5.15?

Comment: I'd install 20.04 if my hardware is older. Will be supported until 2025

Comment: @kanehekili You are right. Maybe I should stick to 20.04

Comment: I downgraded to 5.11 no problems. You can use ubuntu mainline for that.

Comment: i downgraded to 5.13 with no problems. touchpad is working again. i used mainline. also needed to set the default kernel in grub to 5.13 .. using GRUB_DEFAULT .. because 5.15 is still installed.

Comment: @ruthless Yes I am aware of that. Infact upgrading kernel to 5.18 from mainline is also working.

Comment: I downgraded to 5.13 but to make it work I had to disable secure boot in BIOS. Without that I was getting "error: bad shim signature".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try below actions to use [pimlie / ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
chmod +x ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh

# search and find your wanted version
ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -r | grep 5.13

# install that version kernel
ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i v5.13.19

# get all menuentries
grep 'menuentry \|submenu ' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -f2 -d "'"

# change the grub configuration
vi /etc/default/grub
from: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
to: GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.19-051319-generic"

# update grub
update-grub

# reboot
reboot now

# verify
uname -r
```

Comment: To make it work in my case (Lenovo Legion 5 15ITH6) I had to disable secure boot in BIOS. Without that I was getting "error: bad shim signature".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after clean install of lubuntu-22 on Dell-Inspiron_5570, experienced "elantech touchpad problem" due to which "two finger scrolling" was not working. After 4-5 hectic days on the work dealing with the arrow keys on keyboard, I found it as kernel incompatibility. Then, tried installing different kernel versions following @xiaojueguan answer and found the version 5.15.0-58-generic to be working for me.

Comment: I use it in arm64 , kunpeng910 server. OK!

Comment: Following the instructions found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack tell you how to downgrade from the HWE kernel stack to GA; see "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel*"  as the 5.15 kernel is the GA kernel stack of Ubuntu (*using the GA kernel stack will mean you get security fixes; using a specific kernel leaves backport security fixes to yourself to perform*)