# Ubuntu 22.04 screen flickering on DELL 5480

Tags: 22.04, dell

I've installed a Ubuntu 22.04 server on my DELL 5480 but now the screen is flickering incessantly.

`lspci | grep VGA`

> VGA compatible controller: Intel corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics
> 520] (rev 07)

Is it possible to update the driver or is there another solution ?

Comment: Did it work better with another OS before?

Comment: You can always search for your model [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-in/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=3pmv4) and download the drivers on that webpage.

Comment: @Pilot6 Dunno. Actually the flickering occurs in terminal mode (install + starting + login). After `startx` is being launched (desktop mode) the flickering stops.

Comment: Add `startx` to your startup applications (If you don't know how to do that, follow this [article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/manage-startup-applications-ubuntu/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution thanks to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404771/screen-flicker-after-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-22-04).

Edit the grub file:
`sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

Add the following values to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` parameter:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2"

`sudo update-grub`

Reboot

Now the flickering is gone.