# Kernel 5.19.0.35 broke HDMI audio output

Tags: sound, hdmi

Running Ubuntu 22.04.2, since the kernel 5.19.0-35, there is an issue with the HDMI audio output. Can you help me to retrieve my HDMI audio output please?

[image]
[image]

With kernel 5.19.0-32, HDMI output is found:

```
$ uname -a
    xxx 5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    cat /proc/asound/cards
     0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                          HDA Intel PCH at 0xa0340000 irq 127
     1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                          HDA ATI HDMI at 0xa01a0000 irq 128
```

With kernel 5.19.0-35, HDMI output is not found:

```
$ uname -a
    xxx 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    $ cat /proc/asound/cards
     0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                          HDA Intel PCH at 0xa0340000 irq 127

$ inxi -Fam
Audio:
          Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH-V cAVS vendor: Micro-Star MSI
            driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel alternate: snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
            bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a3f0 class-ID: 0403
          Device-2: AMD Navi 10 HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie:
            gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 03:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:ab38
            class-ID: 0403
          Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
          Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
          Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
        
$ aplay -l
**** Liste des périphériques matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0 : ALC897 Analog [ALC897 Analog]
Sous-périphériques : 1/1
Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
        
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V cAVS
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 HDMI Audio
```

Comment: Had the same issue, downgrading the kernel fixed it for me as well, but I needed to do it the hard way since it was a fresh install on a new system. I downgraded to 5.15.104. https://askubuntu.com/a/1420274/549798

Comment: I experienced the same issue with kernel 5.19.0-35 on my hardware Gigabyte model: F2A68HM-H.
As of April 14th 2023 HDMI sound is working fine with Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon. It's currently using Kernel: 5.15.0-69.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, I removed the kernel concerned and back to the previous kernel.

```
sudo apt --purge remove linux-headers-5.19.0-35 linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic linux-modules-5.19.0-35-generic
```