# Ubuntu 22.04.2 - hdmi issue after update - video but no audio

Tags: 22.04

Immediately after the most recent update (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS), i have lost hdmi audio. Video works (is displayed on monitor), but there is no sound. Furthermore, there are no options to select the hdmi / monitor source from the settings page, even when the hdmi lead is plugged in, even from system boot. I have also edited the grub file as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403575/hdmi-audio-issue-ubuntu-22-04).

I have also disabled virtulisation from the bios (had docker installed), killed and restarted pulseaudio, nothing seems to work.

What has gone wrong? Has anyone found a fix?

Comment: Same issue here, because of new kernel. https://askubuntu.com/q/1458031/546652

Comment: Any idea of a fix / when a patch is due? Had to happen when i was stoked for a season finale.

Comment: I reverted to the previous kernel from the grub menu, which has HDMI fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

I too had to revert to previous kernel from the grub menu.

hold the [shift] key when Ubuntu is loading, Choose 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' from the Grub screen and load the previous kernel version.  {this is a temporary solution until next reboot}

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-revert-to-previous-kernel

for Permanent Solution (in case you don't know)