# No sound through HDMI after update

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have a laptop connected to a TV via HDMI. Initially the sound did not work, and I had to modify something in a file somewhere to get it to work. Clearly a highly descriptive recollection of events that occurred a year ago, I know. A recent update (one which I have avoided for a long time) broke the sound. I've attempted to find the original fix but no luck.

`lspci` lists the device I am looking for:

```
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
```

`aplay -l` does not list anything except the analogue Realtek device. Not what I'm looking for.

`pavucontrol` lists only the internal speakers and the unplugged headphone jack. No trace of the HDMI audio on any of the tabs. Same with`alsamixer`. Nothing.

`pactl list sinks` only returns one result, being the analogue device

`cat /proc/asound/cards` returns:

```
1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HDA-Audio Generic
                     HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0b44000 irq 40
```

I'm not sure what other information to provide. I haven't included the full output of some of the commands above as the laptop is not networked. Manually typing some of those outputs would be difficult to say the least. If any of them could reveal information that might be of relevance, let me know, and I'll see what I can do.

In the meantime, anyone know what the solution might be? From the little I recall of the solution, it involved editing a file, not installing anything, or using any programs with a GUI. Potentially adding or editing some lines to do with "intel"? I'm even less sure about that one, given the AMD hardware.

Comment: Back to previous kernel: https://askubuntu.com/a/1458405/546652

Comment: @NicolasSmith Looks like that solved it. I ended up wiping the drive and starting with a fresh install. As soon as the kernel updated, the problem returned. Reverting to the old kernel was the solution