# Ubuntu 22.04 lost the ability to select HDMI sound out after system update

Tags: sound, hdmi

System: AMD A8-7600 (onboard graphics) Radeon R7 KAVERI
Motherboard: Gigabyte AMD FM2+ A68HM-H

HDMI sound out to my home theater via HDMI was working fine for months until a recent system update. I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 onto a different drive and HDMI was available.  I then allowed the system to fully update and once again the HDMI sound was gone.

As a workaround, I have installed a GeForce GTX 750 Ti and I'm using its HDMI output. The sound is back and HDMI is available once again in the Settings menu.

This is the output with the above workaround installed.

```
Audio: Device-1: AMD Kaveri HDMI/DP 
Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
Device-2: AMD FCH 
Azalia driver: snd_hda_intel 
Device-3: NVIDIA GM107 High Definition Audio 
[GeForce 940MX] driver: snd_hda_intel Sound 
Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic 
running: yes 
Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 
running: yes
```

Comment: Can you include the output of the `inxi -A` command?

Comment: This is the output with the above workaround installed.
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD FCH Azalia driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-3: NVIDIA GM107 High Definition Audio [GeForce 940MX]
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes

Comment: Back to previous kernel
https://askubuntu.com/a/1458405/546652